# Is it possible to get a Level 3 Machine Gun in Blood Stained Sanctuary?

Tags: cave-story

In the final level of the game, Blood Stained Sanctuary, is it possible to get a Level 3 Machine Gun by the end of the first room? An extra "Jet Pack" would be nice for completing that area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there are enough exp capsules to get any weapon to level 3, including the machine gun.

You'll need to be careful though since you all spikes are instant-death traps and you don't get the boost from the MG until you get it to level 3.

Note though, per your question, you cannot get it to Level 3 by the end of the first room. By the second room, yes.

Comment: Dang, the second room is the one I would need it on the most.